# Vue, dayjs wrong output on template

Tags: vue.js, dayjs

In the console log, I have `15:14`, but in the template, I got `12:14`. Why?

```html
<template>
    <span>{{ date }}</span> <!-- **expected** Thu, 25 Feb 2021 15:14:04 Thu, **got** 25 Feb 2021 12:14:04 GMT -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    date() {
      const date = getStatusDate(); // returns string 2021-02-25 15:14:04
      return dayjs(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss+z')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is converting the timezone also.  the solution could be getStatusDate return a datetime format that also informs the timezone or you do the time shifting manually.

Comment: how can i change it manually if idk user timezone? Any advice?

Comment: new Date().getTimezoneOffset() gets the timezone offset in minutes. let me know if this works so I can post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input date string has no timezone specified, the underlying `Date` object in `dayjs` assumes local timezone. The template's string interpolation [leads to `dayjs().toString()`, which uses `Date.prototype.toUTCString()`](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/b8d2e32/src/index.js#L368), causing the display of different times.

The solution is to use `dayjs().format()` to control the format of the output string:

```js
dayjs(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

```js
const getStatusDate = () => '2021-02-25 15:14:04'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    date() {
      const date = getStatusDate()
      return dayjs(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ date }}</p>
</div>
```